# How to randomly pick a string from a list, and insert it into a new one?

Tags: python, list, random

This code breaks down one of the methods of selecting a random element within a list, and inserting it within a new one.

Hopefully this is more explanatory than the original question, as I have tried to explain each line of code

```
#Allows us to use randrange specifically
from random import randrange

#Our list of objects to pick from
objectList = ["Box","Table","Chair","Bed"]
#The empty list we are adding to
emptyList = []

#Find out how many objects are in the list
numObjects = len(objectList) # Will return 4

#Pick a random number between 0 and numObjects - 1
randomIndex = randrange(numObjects)

#Select and store an object at the randomIndex in objectList

#If randomIndex = 2, the selectedObject would be "Chair"
#as the first index is 0
#"Box"   - index 0
#"Table" - index 1
#"Chair" - index 2
#"Bed"   - index 3
selectedObject = objectList[randomIndex]

#Add the object to the empty list
emptyList.append(selectedObject)

#To simplify picking the random object you should use this
selectedObject = objectList[randrange(len(objectList))]
emptyList.append(selectedObject)

#Or furthermore
emptyList.append(objectList[randrange(len(objectList))])
```

Comment: Questions need to include enough information to be answerable **in the question itself**, not behind a link. Image links are included in this -- like any other link, they can break, and we don't want linkrot to make parts of our Q&A database useless.

Comment: You should include the code in the question (for that, just add 4 spaces in front of each line of code) so that we just have to copy/paste it to see what it does.

Comment: You can include snippets of code as code blocks within your post using the `{}` button in the editor or by [adding 4 spaces before each line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Please copy the code and the error message into the question itself. Using photos is highly discouraged.

Comment: Posting your code as an image makes it harder for people to help.

Comment: Please post the source code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: What's more, some parentheses got cut off the screenshot

Comment: Also, it would help a lot if you said _specifically_ what the problem is: what  you _want_ the code to do, what the code is doing _instead_, and what the _difference_ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, it seems like you want to create a list of a bunch of random features. The way I would personally go about this is by using the random method `Choice`

Choice allows us to pick a string from a list, then we use a function called `.append` that lets us include it in another list

```
from random import choice

Leaves=["(Pointy ","(Rounded ","(Maple ","(Pine ","(Sticks "]
Trunk=["Oak ","Birch ","Maple ","Ash ","Beech ","Spruce "]
Size=["Extra Large)","Large)","Medium)","Small)","Tiny)"]
Tree=[]
NewCombination = []

while len(Tree)<len(Leaves)*len(Trunk)*len(Size):
    NewCombination.append((choice(Leaves)) + (choice(Trunk) + (choice(Size))))

    if Tree != NewCombination:
        Tree=Tree+NewCombination
print(Tree)
```

I have also made it much easier to see the printed list by including brackets and spaces in your original three lists